# Change Label text in a ContainerView on click of a button from other class (Uiviewcontroller)

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-development

I got small `containerView` with `UILabel` on main app screen. I got `UIButton` on main `UIViewController`. I want to change text of `label` that belongs to `containerView` class by clicking button in `UIViewController`.
I try to make it with delegation, but for some reason i got a mistake (Unwraping optional)...

I try to make it with Protocol, bud method "addText" in ContView dont works((((((

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

var delegate: DelegateProtocol?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {

delegate?.addText(String2: "123")

}}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
   protocol DelegateProtocol {

    func addText(String2: String)
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
class ContViewController: UIViewController, DelegateProtocol {


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "con" {

            let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController
            vc.delegate = self
        }
    }


    func addText(String2: String) {

        label.text = String2

    }


    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}
```

Comment: Show some code and the the error you got.

Comment: Error is the method addText is dont execute in ContViewController from button touchUp inside in ViewController class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first make an global variable in your view controller

```
private var viewController: YourVC?
```

then give your container view segue an identifier and do follwing

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "yourviewcontroller Segue identifiew" {  //your container view segue identifier
        viewController = segue.destination as? SelectedImageVC
    }
}
```

now you can use you `viewController` to access label in your containerview controller like

```
if let controller = viewController {
    controller.yourlabel.text = "text you want"
}
```

Comment: Bro, your code dont work... Or maybe i do somrthing wrong.

Comment: Bro your code dont help me, but i accept your answer. TY